# django-ajax-selects - How to keep the selected option

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-ajax-selects

I was able to successfully deploy django-ajax-selects. When I search for a value on my form I'm able to find it and "lock" that value on the below "display deck" (that's how it's called in the documentation), save everything as expected when I submit the form, however as you can see the text field goes empty. Therefore, the fact that the value I selected disappears from the actual text field is quite confusing to the average person, so I'd like guidance on how I could keep the selected value in both, the "display deck" and the actual text field. I would also like to delete the selected value from both places after clicking on the trash icon (if i needed to). This is how it currently looks when I have selected a value from the dropdown and it's ready to be submitted.
[image]

Can anyone please provide guidance on how to do that please? My guess is that a customization needs to happen in the Customizing Template [documentation](https://django-ajax-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Custom-Templates.html).

Here's my fairly standard **forms.py**

```
class StartConversationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Conversation 
        fields = ('circle','conversation', 'detail','conversation_type')

    circle = AutoCompleteSelectField('circles', required=True,  help_text=None)
```

Thanks so much in advance